# Summarize events per session with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, user-interaction

Is it possible to summarize events per user (session)?

I have a subscription (CTA) field on the page.
Further down, there is a small just-for-fun questionnaire.

I want to check, if a user is more willing to subscribe if they performed the questionnaire, or if that doesn't matter at all.

So I track an event for a subscription (I configured this as a "Goal" (conversion)), and an event for the questionnaire. But how can I summarize these two events for each user?

Or do I have to implement this analytics with my own `AJAX-PHP-MYSQL` setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "a row in the report per indidivual user" then GA does not support this (at least not by default, you would need to store an identifier in a custom dimension and query by that).

If you are looking for aggregated numbers you can create a segment ("include sessions where event equals  AND goal conversions for  > 1". You can then apply the segment to your query to get the total number of users with both conditions, or add more dimensions e.g. to break down by channel, region etc.